# How can I perform some commands on Intersystem cache from shellscript?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, aix, intersystems-cache

I want to perform some commands on Intersystem cache from shell script. One solution which I know is through making a config file but the problem is I dont know how to use config file through shell script. Is there any other solution for this...

for example what I have to run on cache is

```
csession instancename
zn "area"
area>D ^%RI
Device:some/device/path
Next: It should take enter
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished from a Linux shell, simply keep a log of the commands you need to perform and then put them into a script. Here's an example of logging into Cache and writing "Hello world" -- note that this also assumes you need to authenticate.

```
echo -e "username\npassword\nW \"Hello world\"\nH\n" | csession instance
```

Note that every command you would have run manually is in there and separated by "\n", this is the character that represents the "Enter" key.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible (for some operating systems) to run the Cache terminal in batch mode.  For example:

```
echo: off
wait for:Username
send: SYS<CR>
wait for:Password
send: XXX<CR>
echo: on

logfile: Somepath\myFile.log

send: ZN "AREA"
wait for:AREA>

send: D ^%RI
wait for:Device:
send: some/device/path
wait for:Next:
send: <CR>
```

This is documented in [the Intersystems cache terminal documentation](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20101/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GTER_intro), especially [the using terminal in batch mode section](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20082/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GTER_batch) and [the terminal scripts section](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20082/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GTER_scripts_general#GTER_example_script).

Comment: I still didn't got it. I am new at shellscripting and cache

Comment: Did you read any of the documentation?  What did you try?  What don't you get?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question .. as I came across the same thing and so with a little R&D I found a work around to this problem. Which is very cool and simple.

Let's say I have this file (can be with any extension with each command in separate line)

#### myScript.scr

```
     zn "%SYS"
     for e="a","b","c" { w e,! }
```

So passing it to cache terminal in case of UNIX is using `csession` with linux PIPE (|) operator

> cat myScript.scr | csession {instance_name}

#### Eg.

```
cat myScript.scr | csession CACHE
```

#### output

```
     a
     b
     c
```

#### Note:

```
• Don't separate a command in multiple lines else `csession` will through <SYNTAX> error. (See how I wrote the *for* loop)
• Extra knowledge - Intersystem Ensemble supports *Cache Terminal Batch Mode* in Windows case... While in linux there is no cterm to take the scripts.. 
• But linux gives you a work around to do this ;).
```

Hope this helps you guys!! cheers :D